# Facebook Graph API calls

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When i use GET /v2.4/{photo-id}  in graph API explorer

It throws an error :
    `{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: {user-id}",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 803
  }
}`

what does this really mean ? any help

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be passing `{user-id}` which is not a valid data to query about.

Instead, use the below code without {user-id}:

```
GET /v2.4/{photo_id}
```

{photo_id} is an id of a post most probably in the `userid_postid` ("10000_00001") format.